# Compare dates in Day.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, dayjs

How do I check if **'Tue Jan 31 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100'** is ***the same day and month*** as **'2023-01-31T18:45:00-06:00'**?
It's very confusing.

```
let dates = [
{slot: '2023-01-31T18:45:00-06:00'}
{slot: '2023-01-31T19:00:00-06:00'}
{slot: '2023-01-31T19:15:00-06:00'}
{slot: '2023-01-31T19:30:00-06:00'}
{slot: '2023-01-31T19:45:00-06:00'}
{slot: '2023-01-31T20:00:00-06:00'}
]

let dayjsDate = dayjs('Tue Jan 31 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100') // DateJS object!

dates.forEach(x => {
let oneSlot = dayjs(x.slot)
   if (oneSlot.isSame(dayjsDate, 'day')
        && oneSlot.isSame(dayjsDate, 'month')) {
        console.log("Yes")
   } else {
        console.log("No")
   }
})
```

Comment: I think the problem is that dayjs is transforming dayjsDate to your local time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not actually familiar with Day.js or momentjs (your 2 tags) but I believe you can do this in good old vanilla JS (meaning no packages necessary).

I'll preface this by saying I'm no expert in Dates in JS, so my approach might be a weird one.

I like to "normalize" dates without timezones, so I start with your source one that you called `dayjsDate` as

```
let source_date = "Tue Jan 31 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100".split(' ');

source_date.pop();

source_date = new Date(source_date); //log would give "Tue Jan 31 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" since I'm in EST
```

(or if you want to do it in a single line:
`let source_date = new Date("Tue Jan 31 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100".split(' ').slice(0,-1));` )

Then, with the values in your array, since we only care about the date portions, I would do:

```
let dates = [ //directly from your post, but I added commas
  {slot: '2023-01-31T18:45:00-06:00'},
  {slot: '2023-01-31T19:00:00-06:00'},
  {slot: '2023-01-31T19:15:00-06:00'},
  {slot: '2023-01-31T19:30:00-06:00'},
  {slot: '2023-01-31T19:45:00-06:00'},
  {slot: '2023-01-31T20:00:00-06:00'},
];

let cleaned_dates = dates.map(x => new Date(x.slot.substring(0, 10) + 'T00:00:00')); //an array of dates
```

We can now easily compare the dates, by virtue of something like:

```
cleaned_dates.forEach(x => isSame(x, source_date));

function isSame(date_1, date_2) {
    let same = (date_1.getMonth() === date_2.getMonth()) && (date_1.getDate() === date_2.getDate());
    if (same) console.log('Same');
    else console.log('Different');
    return same;
}
```

If you would also like to compare by year, you can easily add another like as `&& date_1.getFullYear() === date_2.getFullYear()`. These are native JS functions that work with `Date` objects.

Functions in JS are "hoisted" so they load before everything else, so they can be called before they are declared.

Comment: Don't forget to choose accept this answer if it solved your problem! Or let me know if you have any questions.